# regex to find word and alphanumeric pattern

Tags: regex

I want find something similar to

Control Number

Blah BLah BLah Blah BLah BLah Blah BLah BLahBlah BLah BLah Blah BLah BLahBlah BLah BLah
vBlah BLah BLahvBlah BLah BLahBlah BLah BLahBlah BLah BLahBlah BLah BLah

ASDF123456dsa9

I have tried formulas like:

```
(control number)[\S\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}\s
```

but it picks up everything but I only want it to find "control number ASDF123456dsa9" that is only 14 characters in length,  especially if their is multiple instances.

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier (reluctant quantifier).

Comment: Put your control number value in a group `([a-zA-Z0-9]{14})`